# Used recovery software, really strange results

Tags: data-recovery

I was using a data recovery software tool today, Disk Drill and it gave me really strange results, pictures I have literally never seen before. So I thought it was caching from my browser that saved to my pc and got deleted, but there are also nudes in there and I don't watch any porn on my PC nor do I save those kind of pictures on my pc. I don't visit any strange sites on my pc and I use an add blocker. Can anyone explain me how this is possible? The PC is fresh from the store, my only guess would be is that they used second hand HHD's but that would be strange, because it was a franchise store in my country with all first-hand stuf. My OS is windows 8.

Answer (score 3):

If your OS is Windows 8, that's not a new computer, it's almost certainly second hand. Win10 came out in 2015.

Presumably the previous owner did a poor job of wiping the drive before selling it on.
Be a good actor & ignore it all.

Comment: I bought it when win10 wasn't there and fresh from the shop first hand. Im running windows 8.1 btw, not 8 my bad.

Comment: There's still no other explanation for how they got there. If you didn't do it, somebody else did, & didn't properly wipe their tracks.